# count width for 4x verse container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, sum

I would like to create easy script for counting width and sum for width of container.
Here's example:
http://codepen.io/Szymon_Dziewonski/pen/ycJxf

I need to specify width of `#inner` if i want 4 line on this specific `#container` width.
If not `ul li` just go in one line.
As you can see my count isnt good enough for this problem when there is no exact amount of `li`.
For example

10 `li` = (40 * 100px) /4 = 1000px so it is good anwser #inner will be 1000px and will be 4 lines (10 + 10 + 10 + 10) `li's`

but if:

15 `li` = (25 * 100px) /4 = 625px so it is #inner 625 4 lines * 6 `li's` + 1 `li's`

Problem is when number of `li` is odd or even = result is different

If anyone has idea how to solve this problem I would be most pleased and help will be appreciate!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var accum_width = 0;
var test = Math.ceil($('#inner li').size()/4)*102;

if(test > 1122){
  $('#container').width(test);
}else{
    $('#container').width(1122);
}
```

thats the anwser 'math.ceil'